# A recursive description of the smallest divisor-closed subsemigroup containing a set

Tags: reference-request, ra.rings-and-algebras, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $S$ be a semigroup and $\widehat{S}$ be its unitization, i.e., the monoid obtained from $S$ by adjoining an identity element if necessary (so that $\widehat{S} = S$ when $S$ is already a monoid).

We say that $a$ divides (or is a divisor of) $b$ in $S$, and we write $a \mid_S b$, if $a, b \in S$ and $b = uav$ for some $u, v \in \widehat{S}$. A divisor-closed subsemigroup of $S$ is then a subsemigroup $T$ of $S$ such that, if $a \mid_S b$ and $b \in T$, then $a \in T$. E.g., the empty semigroup and $S$ are both divisor-closed subsemigroups of $S$.

Given a set $X \subseteq S$, the intersection of all divisor-closed subsemigroups of $S$ containing $X$ is itself a divisor-closed subsemigroup of $S$ (containing $X$), hereinafter denoted by $[\![X]\!]_S$. This notion is quite useful when it comes to studying the arithmetic of semigroups, partly because it is often possible to show that certain properties hold "locally" (i.e., for the divisor-closed subsemigroups of the form $[\![x]\!]_S$ with $x \in S$) if and only if they hold globally. For instance, the semigroup $S$ is atomic (i.e., every non-unit of $\widehat{S}$ factors as a product of atoms) iff $[\![x ]\!]_S$ is atomic for every non-unit $x \in S$. (Here, an atom of a semigroup $N$ is a non-unit of its unitization $\widehat{N}$ that does not factor as a product of two non-units in $\widehat{N}$, and I'm writing $[\![x ]\!]_S$ in place of $[\![\{x\} ]\!]_S$.)

When $S$ is, say, commutative, $[\![X]\!]_S$ has a neat description — it is the subsemigroup (of $S$) generated by the divisors of the elements of the subsemigroup generated by $X$. Things are not so smooth in general. However, it is still possible to describe $[\![X]\!]_S$ as the union of the terms of the sequence $D_0(X)$, $D_1(X)$, $\ldots$ of subsets of $S$ defined by taking $D_0(X) := X$ and letting $D_n(X)$ be, for each $n \in \mathbb N^+$, the subsemigroup generated by the divisors of the elements in $D_{n-1}(X)$. In some situations, this is more than enough to do something, which leads me to the following:

> **Question.** Do you have a reference for the "iterative description" of the subsemigroup $[\![X]\!]_S$ outlined in the above?

It is only recently that I've seen divisor-closed subsemigroups being used in the non-commutative setting (I myself have used them more than once), but that's probably ignorance from my side. It is highly likely that divisor-closedness is referred to in a different way in the larger literature on semigroups (in my field, the term is well established). Clarifying this aspect is also part of the motivation for the question.

Comment: Note an answer, just a comment:  Whenever there is a closure operator in play, you have a top-down construction (the intersection you mentioned) and a bottom-up construction (closing, then closing again, etc...).  So, if you are satisfied with showing that there is a natural closure operator, you could just refer to the literature on closure operators for the "iterative description" you want.  (In your case it stabilizes in countable many steps because the operator is finitary.)

Comment: @PaceNielsen Do you have in mind any candidate for the closure operator alluded to in your comment? I'm not sure whether I would be satisfied with this approach, but I'm a big fan of high tech. I guess that much will ultimately depend on the details.

Comment: There are actually two closure operators in play.  The "subgroup generated by" operator, and the "set of divisors" operator.  I'll leave it to you to check that both of these operators satisfy the usual three axioms of a closure operator https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_operator  They are also both finitary.  Now, the joint closure under these two operators is just the alternating application of one operator after the other (your iteration) [or the intersection you described].  It only takes an $\omega$-chain of alternations because of the finitariness.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I had never realized that "the subgroup generated by" and "the set of divisors" can be viewed as finitary closure operators. That's cool! Let me denote the 1st operator by $\Pi$, the 2nd by $\Delta$, and the composition "$\Pi$ after $\Delta$" by $\Gamma$. I agree that, in the notation of the OP, $D_n(X)=\Gamma^{\circ n}(X)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$, where $\Gamma^{\circ n}$ is the $n$th iterate of $\Gamma$. How does this show that $[\![X]\!]_S=\bigcup_n\Gamma^{\circ n}(X)$ *from general principles*? Not very familiar with closure operators and clearly missing something. Any refs?

Comment: In general, it might take longer than an $\omega$-length union to achieve stability.  But your operators are special.  A closure operator $C$ is called finitary when $x\in C(S)$ exactly when $x\in C(S_0)$ for some finite subset $S_0\subseteq S$.  So, when talking about algebras with operations of finite arity, the "subalgebra generated by" operator is a finitary closure operator.  Clearly, the "set of divisors" operator is also finitary.  Now, a general fact is that if $\Pi$ and $\Delta$ are finitary, and $\Gamma=\Pi\circ \Delta$, then joint closure happens at the union you wrote.

Comment: I don't know a reference off the top of my head for that last fact,  The proof is super easy.  Let $T=\bigcup_n \Gamma^{\circ n}(S)$.  It suffices to show closure under $\Pi$ (as the argument is similar for $\Delta$).  Let $x\in \Pi(T)$.  Then $x\in \Pi(T_0)$ for some finite subset $T_0\subseteq T$.  Thus, $T_0\subseteq \Gamma^{\circ m}(S)$ for a sufficiently large $m$.  Then $x\in \Pi(T_0)\subseteq \Gamma^{\circ m+1}(S)\subseteq T$.

Comment: @PaceNielsen I continue to miss something. AFAICS, what you show in the last two comments is that, for each subset $X$ of the sgrp $S$, the set $T:=\bigcup_n\Gamma^{\circ n}(X)$ is "$\Gamma$-closed" (i.e., $\Gamma(T) = T$). But this is not my problem with your "high-tech argument". My problem is that I don't see why $T$ equals $[\![X]\!]_S$ (the intersection of all divisor-closed subsgrps of $S$ containing $X$).  Actually, I know how to prove it. The point is rather that I don't understand how this should follow from the kind of "general principles" mentioned in your 1st comment [tbc].

Comment: @PaceNielsen Let $C(X)$ be the set of all $\Gamma$-closed subsets of $S$ that contain $X$ (I keep the notation from my previous comment). It seems clear to me that $Y\in C(X)$ iff $Y$ is a divisor-closed subsgrp of $S$ containing $X$. So, $$[\![X]\!]_S=\bigcap_{Y\in C(X)} Y = \bigcap_{X \subseteq Y\subseteq S} \Gamma(Y).$$
To my understanding, your 1st comment is suggesting that, *by some general properties of closure operators*, the intersection $\bigcap_{X \subseteq Y\subseteq S} \Gamma(Y)$ and the union $\bigcup_n \Gamma^{\circ n}(X)$ are equal. What's a ref? That's my question.

Comment: It is not true that $\bigcap_{Y\in C(X)}Y = \bigcap_{X\subseteq Y\subseteq S}\Gamma(Y)$ because $\Gamma$ itself might not be a closure operator.  (The composition of closure operators is not necessarily a closure operator.)  The set on the left is $\Gamma$-closed (and hence both $\Pi$- and $\Delta$-closed), and hence equals $\bigcup_{n}\Gamma^{\circ n}(X)$ [since this is $\Gamma$-closed by the argument I gave, and clearly minimal].

Comment: For a reference, you might try Bergman's introduction to general algebra.  There is a lot on closure operators...don't have time right now to look through it all...https://math.berkeley.edu/~gbergman/245/3.2.pdf

Comment: @PaceNielsen Right, $\Gamma$ need not be a closure op (otherwise, we would have had $\Gamma^{\circ n} = \Gamma$ for all $n = 1, 2, \ldots,$ and life would have been easier). I'll have a look at the PDF linked in your last comment. Thanks! Maybe I'm wrong again, but *in hindsight* all this looks like an elegant rewording of the same proof that Pedro Garcia-Sanchez and I have in our work (which motivated the question in the OP). The main difference is that we never mention closures.

Comment: I believe "Exercise 6.3:4(ii)" would be an appropriate reference for the claim about the joint closure stabilizing at the $\omega$th stage.  [Writing the semigroup operation multiplicatively, take the set $G$ in that exercise to consist of all pairs $(\{x,y\},xy)$ (forcing closure under being a semigroup) together with all pairs $(\{x\},d)$ whenever $d$ is a divisor of $x$ (forcing closure under divisors).]

Comment: @PaceNielsen I agree with your last comment. But overall, this is not really the kind of ref I was looking for. I'm still hoping for something closer to the spirit of what I have in mind, that is, a ref where the "iterative description" in the OP is proved, possibly in a generalized form, without any need for the reader to work out too many additional details (before getting to see what's going on in the case of interest). Many thanks anyway, the exchange was very fruitful for me.